# Azure QnaMaker chat logs are not generated

Tags: azure-qna-maker

The [GenerateAnswer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/metadata-generateanswer-usage) API describes userId if sent in a request will be recorded in chat logs which as far as I could see do not seem to get generated.

Do chat logs get generated by default? or am I required to provision resources or make configuration changes for logging to take effect?

And please can you point me to Azure documentation if any that describes the logging aspects of QnA Maker in detail?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

QnA Maker does not generate chatlogs by default. They currently do not offer any APIs to store chat logs.

Assuming you are using it in a form of a chatbot where question and answers are displayed concurrently, you could create a database instance that is stored locally such as SQL Server 2016.

Then by generating a unique GUID based on time of user visit store each chatlog in a table with the Primary key as 'GUID' followed by 'Question' and 'Answer' and 'Time'.

*Example of potential answer model*

```
namespace Frontend.Data {
   public class Message {
      [Key]
      public string MessageId { get; set; }
      public string ConversationId { get; set; }
      public string Question { get; set; }
      public string Answer { get; set; }
      public DateTime MessageReceivedAtDateTime { get; set; }

      public Message(string messageId, string conversationId, string question, string answer, string datestring) {
         MessageId = messageId;
         ConversationId = conversationId;
         Answer = answer;
         Question = question;
         MessageReceivedAtDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse(datestring).UtcDateTime;
      }

      public Message() {}
   }
```

However, you may have to tinker around with saving the question and answers as the user exits the program.

Depending on the language you are implementing QnA Maker, you may need to tweak some of these changes

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb?view=sql-server-2017

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.newguid?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Thanks for your response. I do not intend to roll out a custom solution. It seems they had this feature in the preview version not in the GA version. Application Insights can be used alternatively, however it needs some knowledge on how queries work, more at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/get-analytics-knowledge-base